# How to skip unknown number of rows with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

In the example below I can see df.columns only for data from the first row. However I would like to use the code for different files. For some of them first several rows are empty. I do not know the exact number of rows so I cannot use f.e: skiprows=4. How can I find the number of empty rows which should be skipped?

```
path = r'D:\columntest.xlsx'
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(path)
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, sheet_name=0)

print(df.columns)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the drop_na method:

```
df.dropna(how='all', inplace=True)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.drop(0)
```

Comment: I needed to change 'drop_na' into 'dropna', but it doesn't work. When column names are not given in the first row, it prints names: 'Unnamed: 0', 'Unnamed: 1' and so on.

Comment: I added some lines to my original answer.  I needed to you the search function to get this.

Comment: It works when column names are given in row 2,3,4,5,6..., but it doesn't work when they appear in row 1. I get an error then - "single positional indexer is out-of-bounds".

Comment: It works when I added: c = df.columns[0], and then: if c == 'Unnamed: 0': your solution. When column names are given in the first row, it just goes further.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of this solution is to load your excel sheet into a data frame. Then store it into a csv file. Finally, we open the csv file and remove all the rows with double semicolons.

```
import pandas as pd

# load excel file
path_load = 'D:/columntest.xlsx'
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(path)
df = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=0, header=None)

# store sheet as csv file
path_store = path_load[:-5] + '.csv'
df.to_csv(path_store, sep=';', index=False, header=False)

# process csv to remove lines with `;;`
with open(path_store, "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open(path_store, "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        if line.strip("\n") != ';;':
            f.write(line)

df = pd.read_csv(path_store, sep=';')
```

Comment: I have tried your solution. When I use 'print(df.columns)' at the end, it prints names: 'Unnamed: 0', 'Unnamed: 1' and so on. It only works when column names are given in the first row.

Comment: As long as you do not provide an example dataset it is quite hard to guess what is going wrong. For me it worked on an Excel file with different number of empty lines and with multiple sheets.